# PDO Num Rows with prepared statement

Tags: php, pdo

I am new to PDO and I can't seem to grab the num rows of a select statement... This is my code so far.

```
    $userQuery = $MySQL->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ':username'");
    $userQuery->bindParam(":username", $_POST['username']);

    $userQuery->execute();

    if($userQuery->rowCount() > 0){

    }
```

I've tried googling and read that its harder to do in PDO but I can't find out how to do it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap off `quotes` from placeholder just use it as

```
$userQuery = $MySQL->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");// use without quotes
```

Otherwise it add an extra quotes in your value and you got no result

Comment: Oh wow haha, I didn't know that. Thanks for the help :)